# slds-form-element__label not able to override

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, css, slds

I'm trying to override the default styling of the lightning-input label

I have done below code in css

```
.slds-form-element__label{
font-size: 0.9rem !important;
font-weight:500 !important;
```

}

[image: Console View]

I refreshed the page, logged in logged out multiple time, code is updated in for sure. what and I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [LWC's Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) you cannot override those values using only the class name.

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child

SLDS allows to override them via [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#site-main-content). A lot of properties are setted using [`var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()), which get a custom property name as first parameter and a fallback (default) value.
I.E. `font-size: var(--lwc-formLabelFontSize, 0.75rem);`.

As you can see from the browser's console, the font-size of that label is setted using `--lwc-formLabelFontSize` property.
Since the element that contains that combobox already have a custom css class (`statusFilter`), you could add the following rule into the css file:

```css
:host .statusFilter {
    --lwc-formLabelFontSize: .9rem;
}
```

---

Since the standard label has no font-weight configurable property, you could set [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification)'s variant attribute to `label-hidden` and create your own HTML element, thus you'll be able to set every css property you need.

Comment: voila..  this worked

Comment: any idea on the property for font weight?

Comment: @mvk1991 Unfortunately `font-wight` isn't configurable for that element, but you can hide the label and create your own. I edited the answer adding this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

.You cannot override it using that selector only. You will have to be much more specific in order to override it, for example:

```
.containerInstanceClass div.className > div.otehrclass > div.slds-form-element__label
```

However, I strongly discourage you of using the !important flag in css, as it is not considered a best practice.

Instead of using the slds selector to override the class, add your own class name to the element to scope accordingly.

and if you are using a lightning namespace component, the above wont work due to Shadow DOM. View @RubenDG 's answer for using hooks